# Show the full original source of an email with Python

Tags: python, email, mbox

The main answer of [Reading the mail content of an mbox file using python mailbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567843/reading-the-mail-content-of-an-mbox-file-using-python-mailbox) 
shows how to display the content of an email from a .mbox file:

```
if message.is_multipart():
    content = ''.join(part.get_payload(decode=True) for part in message.get_payload())
else:
    content = message.get_payload(decode=True)
```

However this does not show the "full original source" of the email ; I mean what we can have in nearly all webmails when clicking "Show original message":

```
Delivered-To: ...
Return-Path: ...
...
```

**How to get this with Python `mailbox`?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `message` is a Python `email.message.EmailMessage` object (or the legacy `email.massage.Message` class from before Python 3.5), simply call its `.as_string()` method.

The payload method quite specifically extracts only one MIME part.